# Filtering 4 capital letters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a couple of cells that all vary in their content, but one thing that is the same across all is that they all contain a string of 4 letters which are all capital.

Is there some way for me to only show those 4 capital letters? (through a formula)?

I'm fairly flexible in the solution here, it could either be done in the cell itself or in another cell that references the cell in question.

Comment: can you provide example?

Comment: like:

A1 contains: "The brown fox jumped AGIS"
A2 contains: "The elephant walked ISOR"
A3 contains: "The birds flew UXEN"

What I want is to be able to just show "AGIS", "ISOR" and "UXEN" (either in the original cell or other cells)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "[A-Z]{4}")))
```

[image]

Comment: you're a godsent! thank you that worked like a charm <3